# AngularJS: set two datepickers min and max date with one directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-ui-datepicker

Referring this library http://www.codinginsight.com/angularjs-and-pickadate/ I want to achieve same behavior for minDate and maxDate for  directive which uses jquery datepicker. 
following is my directive code for jquery datepicker in which i want to  disable previous dates selection for endDate datepicker ie second datepicker:

```
 define(['./module'], function(directives) {
'use strict';
  directives.directive('ngDate', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            minDate: '=',
            maxDate: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(element).datepicker({
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                onSelect: function(date) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
            console.log(scope.minDate);
            $(element).datepicker('option','minDate', scope.minDate ? scope.minDate : false);
            $(element).datepicker('option','maxDate', scope.maxDate ? scope.maxDate : false);
            scope.$watch('minDate', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                //element.pickadate('picker').set('min', newValue ? newValue : false);
                $(element).datepicker({minDate: newValue ? newValue : false});
            }, true);
            scope.$watch('maxDate', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                //element.pickadate('picker').set('max', newValue ? newValue : false);
                $(element).datepicker({maxDate: newValue ? newValue : false});
            }, true);
        }
    };

  });
 });
```

Html code which uses directive is

```
 <input type='text' data-ng-model='startDate' class="datepicker datepickerStart" placeholder="dd-mm-yy" id="startDate" data-ng-date='' name="startDate" lower-than="{{endDate}}"  max-date="endDate" readonly='readonly'>

 <input type='text' data-ng-model='endDate' class="datepicker datepickerStart" placeholder="dd-mm-yy" id="endDate" data-ng-date=''  name="endDate" min-date="startDate" readonly='readonly'  >
```

but it gives following error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.

Comment: try this directive http://www.freakyjolly.com/jquery-ui-datepicker-directive-angularjs-min-max-options/